# datalist Аналог в ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net-mvc, razor

привет есть код

```
@Html.TextBox("bro","", new { @list = "browsers", @placeholder = "place"})
        <datalist id="browsers">
            <option>somevalue</option>
        </datalist>
```

подскажите аналог datalist в asp net
UPD.Попробывал

```
<datalist id="browsers">
            @foreach (var c in ViewBag.List)
            {
                <option>@Convert.ToString(c.Name)</option>
            }
        </datalist>
```

не чего но
если вместо `@Convert.ToString(c.Name)` вставить просто строку то ее генерит по количеству прохода цикла

Answer (score 0):

Select2 я думаю Вам подойдет. 
https://select2.github.io/examples.html

И не передавайте через ViewBag модельку.Всегда лучше создать свою модель.